# hide activity name from action bar just in time of creation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Just in time of creation and for about one second or less the action bar shows the name of activity as declared in manifest. Is there any way to avoid this? Of course when activity is created i change programmatically the title.The manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.abc.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/x_logo">
    </activity>
```

and code from fragment which is shown by activity. I change the title of action bar based on what fragment is shown.

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("variable name");
```

from activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hiding the activity name means simply avoiding the text, then call the following in **onCreate** of your `Activity`:

```
getActionBar().setTitle(null);   //if using ActionBar theme
setTitle(null);                  //if using standard theme
```

---

Update

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    final CharSequence title = getActionBar().getTitle();
    getActionBar().setTitle(null);

    //sets the title again after 1 second delay
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I want to have title on action bar. I just don't want to show the default name from manifest for one second before activity is full created.

Comment: this still shows the label from manifest cause the whole think is before any execution of activity's code. I think i the only way to do this is to change the label to "" in manifest. Thank you for your time

Comment: `getActionBar().getTitle()` will first try to provide whatever string you have defined in manifest for that activity. To override this, simply provide your own text in `getActionBar().setTitle("custom_title")`

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to hide a name of activity `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`
 just after onCreate.

Example.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.serverfilelist);
```

Comment: I think this will fail cause the super.onCreate should be the first command.